# Add progress bar to countdown

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I'm working on a simple countdown using [flipclockjs](http://flipclockjs.com/). What I'm trying to do is add a progress bar that is sync to the countdown. I tried to do it, but I can't even get the number of seconds.

Hope you help me.

```js
var clock = $('.my-clock').FlipClock(10, {
  countdown: true,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {    
      setTimeout(function(){
        clock.setTime(10); // proceeding time
        clock.start();
      },1000);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.my-clock {
  text-align:center;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  text-align:center;
  
}
.progressBar{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.progress{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>

<div class="center">
  <div class="my-clock"></div>
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Need more input..so can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you refer to the documentation of [FlipClock](http://flipclockjs.com/api), the interval callback is called on each interval, and I did some dom manipulations to update the progressbar.

```js
let time = 20;
let progress = 0; let counter = 0
var clock = $('.my-clock').FlipClock(time, {
  countdown: true,
  count: 1,
  callbacks: {
    stop: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        clock.setTime(time); // proceeding time
        clock.start();
      },1000);
    },
    interval: function() {
      counter && (progress+=100/time);
      counter ++;
      $('.progressBar .progress').width(progress+ '%');
      if(progress >= 100) {
        progress = 0; counter = 0;
        this.stop()
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.my-clock {
  text-align:center;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
.center {
  text-align:center;
  
}
.progressBar{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.progress{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>

<div class="center">
  <div class="my-clock"></div>
  <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```